# How to pass data to API though Postman?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a rest api Method which is as below:-

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/something", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Object getSomething( @RequestParam String userEmail,Date valid_from, Date valid_till, HttpServletResponse initResponse) {
    //Some functionality inside
}
```

I want to test the API though postman. 
I tried:-

```
http://localhost:8080/something?userEmail="xyz@xyz.com"
```

But this will set data only in the userEmail field.
How do i set the values of valid_from,valid_till and initResponse?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@DateTimeFormat` to configure the format for the `Date` request parameter.It will then parse the request parameters to the `Date` Java object based on this format.

For example :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/something", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Object getSomething(@RequestParam String userEmail ,
 @RequestParam @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyyMMdd") Date valid_from, 
 @RequestParam @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyyMMdd") Date valid_till, 
 HttpServletResponse initResponse) {
    //Some functionality inside
}
```

Then in `Postman` ,send the request by :

```
http://localhost:8080/something?userEmail=xyz@xyz.com&valid_from=20190601&valid_till=20190630
```

One more thing,  I would use the `GET` rather `POST` for the read-only API

Comment: I wish i could change the API. It's already a built rest  API which i have to use and get some data from it. That's why i am trying to figure out that how to set those date and send it along with the link URL in postman.

Comment: Understood, so I suggest you to edit your question to mention this requirements which is about that the API cannot be changed.

Answer (score -1):

First of All change the URL Mapping and it should be like it:

> `http://localhost:8080/parent_Mapping/child_mapping`

Then go to the Postman and send the API Request, with a body having a JSON Body as Show Below in the screenshot:
[image]

Now in order to check what you are getting inside the http request try to print the string that you are getting from the postman as well. as

```
    public Object getSomething( @RequestParam String userEmail,Date valid_from, Date valid_till, HttpServletResponse initResponse) {
    System.out.println(userEmail);
}
```

Comment: Its a @RequestParam which means a query parameter in the URL. So, you can't give URL like http://localhost:8080/parent_Mapping/child_mapping. It will give you missing "userEmail" kind of error.